# Bayesian A/B test for LogNormal data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bayesian, lognormal-distribution

I'm currently working on a (manual) calculation for a bayesian A/B test on logNormal data. I'm currently working with simulated data to increase my understanding.

It's giving me some problems, so I wanted to ask questions. My process:

- Find prior parameters from user-data predating the experiment
- Find posterior distributions for control and variant group
- Look at the difference in posterior samples

The results are:
[image]

The probability of the B variant outperforming the control A should be:
`print(np.mean(trace['difference_B_A1']>0))`

However, this returns a number around 50% even in an A/A test. It seems to me that I should subtract 50% to get the probability that the variant is actually better, but I'm not sure why.

Can someone explain why this probability is 50% in an A/A test and upwards from 50% in a positive A/B test?

Comment: Why not take logs and work with normal models?

Comment: @Glen_b: Is that the normal way to treat this? I'm in favour.

Comment: It's a pretty common approach, at least.

Comment: Why did you chose the Log Normal model?